# How to resolve auto layout constraints for my view

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-autolayout

[image: warnings for autolayout][image: Storyboard screenshot]I need your help.
How can I resolve warnings for auto layout.

Following is my components hierarchy:

View Controller
   View
      - View
        --Table View
          ---Table cell
             1. Title Label
             2. Edit Button
             3. Remove Button

I have provided constraints like below:

Title label:

```
Leading space to superview
trailing space to Edit button
bottom space to superview
top space to superview
```

Edit button

```
trailing space to remove button
leading space to title label
bottom space to superview
top space to superview
```

Remove button

```
Trailing space to superview
width = 40
leading space to edit button
align center Y
height = 40
```

I am receiving warning 'need X and width' for title label, edit and remove button.

Any help?

Comment: are you sure regarding the error? I tried to replicate the same and got a warning just for fixed width constraint. Can you share a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Set **Width Constraint** of the `Edit button` like 40 same as Remove button width.

**Edit button**

```
trailing space to remove button
leading space to title label
width = 40  
bottom space to superview
top space to superview
```

If the button width not fixed then you need to update 
**Content hugging Priority** `Horizontal` value.

> Select the Edit button and change the **Content Hugging Priority** `Horizontal`  value 250 to 251

**OR**

> Select the Title Label and change the **Content Hugging Priority** `Horizontal` value 250 to 249

[image]

Hope this will help.

Comment: I can't fix the width of edit button as it has text in it. Remove button has only image so I have fixed width for it. But even after giving width >= 105, it stills gives me warning as expected width and heigh are different than actual

Comment: is the text is fixed? If fixed then you can set width constraint.

Comment: Text is fixed but localisation can change the width.

Comment: @iAsh have you checked this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the auto Layout pinning button for your storyboard components, I recreated your view and here's what I did for the components.

For Title Label:

[image: Constraints for Button]

For Button:

[image]

[image: Alignment for Button]

For Remove Button:

[image]

And finally trailing space issue fix for  label.

[image]